Logon audit Active Directory
Good afternoon
At the entrance to the domain computer (Active Directory) using the RDP, on the domain controller in the security journal, the successful entrance event 4624 is not recirded
I ask you to help with the clarification of this problem
I set up group policy (Logon/Logoff)
